# Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is from the chapter on Rolle's theorem:

Suppose that $f'(x)>c>0\ \forall x\in[0, \infty)$. Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$

**My attempt:**

Let $g(x)=f(x)-cx$

$g'(x)=f'(x)-c>0$

I feel I'm on the right track but I don't know where to use Rolle's theorem here. Any help would be much appreciated, guys.

Comment: Some hints can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297819/if-fx-gt-0-and-fx-gt-0-then-lim-x-to-inftyfx-infty?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $g'(x)>0$, $g(x)=f(x)-cx >g(0)=f(0)$ for all $x>0$, i.e.
$$f(x)>f(0)+cx,\quad\text{which tends to $+\infty$.}$$

More generally, one can use the following immediate corollary of the *Mean value theorem*:

> Let $f, g $ be differentiable functions on an interval $I$ and $a\in I$. If $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x>a$ in $I$, then 
>   $$f(x)-f(a)>g(x)-g(a)\quad\text{for all }x>a\enspace\text{in }I. $$

Comment: Thanks, but I think you meant $f(x)>f(0)+cx$.

Comment: Oh! yes, of course. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: by the Mean Value Theorem (should be in the same chapter as Rolle's Theorem), for any $x > 0$,
$$
   f(x) = f(0) + f'(z)x > f(0) + cx
$$
where $z$ is some point between $0$ and $x$.